# How to turn cursor(mouse pointer object) into an automated sequence of bmp images?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I want to create a an hour glass movie to display as the mouse pointer when it is waiting for something to complete.  How can I do this.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by creating an animated cursor, and then instructing Windows to display that cursor.
This is precisely how the hourglass cursor is implemented in Windows.

More information about cursors can be found [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648379.aspx).

Using a software package to create and edit your animated cursor files (`*.ani`) makes this process much easier. I use and recommend [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/). Using such software, you can even open the Windows cursors and see how they are constructed.